# Passing parameters from href to jquery dialog

Tags: jquery-ui

I have several delete href on a page.

```
<a href="#" class="delete" data-key=\'{"param1":"'.$id.'", "param2":"'.$id_table.'", "param3":"'.$table.'", "param4":"'.$paginanaam.'", "param5":"'.$template.'", "param6":"'.$lang.'"}\'><i class="fa fa-minus-square fa-lg"></i></a>
```

When a user clicks on this link I'm showing a jquery box to ask if he is sure to delete.

Until now everything is working fine, but I can't the window.location.href with the parameters from data-key to work. Some help would much appreciated.
I have followed this example: http://jsfiddle.net/yayh3/3/

```
<script>
$(".delete").click(
  function() {
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height:170,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Verwijder": function() {
           var me = $(this),
            data = me.data('key');
            window.location.href = "pagina_delete.php?id_record="+data.param1+"&id_table="+data.param2+"&table="+data.param3+"&paginanaam="+data.param4+"&template="+data.param5+"&lang="+data.param6;
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    }
  );
  });
</script>
```

Comment: what is me.data('key') now returning, null ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to capture the context of the clicked element.

Directly within the `click` event handler, you can store the current value of `this` (which will refer to the clicked element), and then you can use this variable within the nested dialog methods/options.

In this case, you would just use `var data = $(self).data('key')` within the dialog method.

```
$(".delete").click(function () {
    var self = this;

    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height: 170,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Verwijder": function () {
                var data = $(self).data('key');
                window.location.href = "pagina_delete.php?id_record=" + data.param1 + "&id_table=" + data.param2 + "&table=" + data.param3 + "&paginanaam=" + data.param4 + "&template=" + data.param5 + "&lang=" + data.param6;
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});
```